# Ubuntu doesn't recognize m4a files

Tags: file-format

I downloaded a few audio files in m4a format from youtube using flashgot plugin in firefox.

The files are showing up as unknown, they don't open on double click. I have to manually right click and select Rhythmbox or VLC everytime to play these files. I also tried adding .m4a after the filename, still doesn't work.

I am using 14.10 on dell n5010

Comment: Have you found a working solution?

Answer (score 10):

Check your M4A file with this command:

```
file /path/to/file.m4a
```

The output should look something like this:

```
ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]
```

If this is so, then you are missing the codec `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Install the package with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Then try again.

Comment: @SaikatPal Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). ;)

Comment: I installed it but it still doesnt recongnise the file.  In  properties it shows "Binary (application/octet-stream)" as file type.

Comment: Then there are probably no M4A files.

Comment: Also on windows when i copied these files to my android phone, they would play. Now when i copy them, my phone doesn't recognise the file.

Comment: Your phone? The comment confuses me a bit.

Comment: The type of M4A is "MPEG-4-Audio (audio/mp4)"

Comment: But it plays when i manually open the file with Rhythmbox.

Comment: With this problem you should open another question. The problem with the missing codec's solved.

Comment: I have the restricted extras installed. But file is still not recognised. Even mp4 videos are not working.

Comment: This is a problem with the flashgot plugin in firefox I think. I have tried clipgrab, now it works.

Answer (score 1):

In the file finder, go to a folder that has some of these files.  Right click on one of the m4a files.  Click on "Properties" (should be at the bottom of the list that pops up).  A screen should come up with tabs in it.  Click on the "Open With" tab.  Select the program you want it and other files of the same type to open with by default.  Click "Set as Default" near the bottom.  Such files should now open with that program when double clicked.