# How to View .m4s files in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, video, video-player, video-editor, video-conversion

Situation: unable to view .m4s files in Ubuntu 16.04
Motivation: I recorded videos by Chrome's addon, GetThemAll, and get a result of 10 .mp4 videos
Unsuccessful viewers/converters: vlc, http://online-audio-converter.com/, not .m4a files as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/610156/25388)

Files in using GetThemAll, `ls -l directory` and `file *`. You see no pieces of information about any init file

```
$ ls -la
total 25148
-rw-rw-r--  1 masi masi  1108289 Jul 26 21:09 segment-10.m4s.m4s
-rw-rw-r--  1 masi masi   288300 Jul 26 21:09 segment-1.m4s(1).m4s
-rw-rw-r--  1 masi masi   837663 Jul 26 21:09 segment-1.m4s.m4s
-rw-rw-r--  1 masi masi   619611 Jul 26 21:09 segment-3.m4s.m4s
-rw-rw-r--  1 masi masi  1495295 Jul 26 21:09 segment-4.m4s.m4s
-rw-rw-r--  1 masi masi  1522196 Jul 26 21:09 segment-5.m4s.m4s
-rw-rw-r--  1 masi masi  2205837 Jul 26 21:09 segment-6.m4s.m4s
-rw-rw-r--  1 masi masi  2108392 Jul 26 21:09 segment-7.m4s.m4s
-rw-rw-r--  1 masi masi  1937186 Jul 26 21:09 segment-8.m4s.m4s
-rw-rw-r--  1 masi masi   734191 Jul 26 21:09 segment-9.m4s.m4s

$ file *
segment-10.m4s.m4s:                                                           data
segment-1.m4s(1).m4s:                                                         data
segment-1.m4s.m4s:                                                            data
segment-3.m4s.m4s:                                                            data
segment-4.m4s.m4s:                                                            data
segment-5.m4s.m4s:                                                            data
segment-6.m4s.m4s:                                                            data
segment-7.m4s.m4s:                                                            data
segment-8.m4s.m4s:                                                            data
segment-9.m4s.m4s:                                                            data
```

I do unsuccessfully and try to open the .mp4 file in VLC without playing

```
# andrew.46
$ cat $(ls -x *.m4s) > testing.mp4

$ file testing.mp4 
testing.mp4: data
```

- Output of `ls -x *.m4s`

  ```
  segment-10.m4s.m4s  segment-1.m4s(1).m4s  segment-1.m4s.m4s
  segment-3.m4s.m4s   segment-4.m4s.m4s     segment-5.m4s.m4s
  segment-6.m4s.m4s   segment-7.m4s.m4s     segment-8.m4s.m4s
  segment-9.m4s.m4s
  ```

Proposals

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/13682218/54964 > https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/player/ but `gpac` not in apt-get
- `cat init.mp4 file.m4s > file.mp4` as proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29175518/54964) did not work. TODO how to get the initialisation segment?

System: Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit

Comment: When you produced the videos you should have had one file with 'init' in the filename and then several more with sequential numbers. Can you give the results of the `ls` command in the directory containing your `.m4s` files?

Comment: You seem to be missing the init file although there is an oddly named file: `segment-1(1).m4s`. Try the following anyway: `cat $(ls -x *.m4s) > testing.mp4` and see if this produces a combined video...

Comment: You are missing a part of your download I suspect. Sorry I could be of no help :(

Comment: @andrew.46 I found a solution. Please, see the wikipage below. There are many videos in one page, which probably is confusing your proposal. - - They are Vimeo videos so just use the plugin in the browser to download them, made for Vimeo.

Comment: `gpac` is available through `apt-get`. You need to enable the "**universe**" repository.

Comment: @mchid Can you please extend the wiki? What is the synapsis of the command? `gpac --help` returns nothing.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Yes, `gpac` is not a command. If you run `dpkg -L gpac` you will see that there are 4 `bin` files and these are the tools you can use. I am not familiar with `gpac`, I just know that it is available through `apt-get` and `apt`. I ran `apt-cache search gpac` to determine this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many videos in the site. I think andrew.46's proposal get confused by the fact. I could not find any init file for Vimeo videos. 
Final solution.

- Study the source code and see if you can see the video sources coming from some major video provider. My case: Vimeo.
- Install the extension: *Download Vimeo Videos, Premium*
- Go to the site and activate videos; just downlod.

Answer (score 0):

Based mchid's comment answer, you can use `gpac`

```
masi@masi:~$ apt show gpac
Package: gpac
Version: 0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5-3+b1
Priority: optional
Section: graphics
Source: gpac (0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5-3)
Maintainer: Debian Multimedia Maintainers <pkg-multimedia-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 829 kB
Depends: gpac-modules-base (= 0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5-3+b1), libgpac4 (= 0.5.2-426-gc5ad4e4+dfsg5-3+b1), libavcodec57 (>= 7:3.2.4) | libavcodec-extra57 (>= 7:3.2.4), libavdevice57 (>= 7:3.2.4), libavformat57 (>= 7:3.2.4), libavresample3 (>= 7:3.2.4), libavutil55 (>= 7:3.2.4), libc6 (>= 2.14), libswscale4 (>= 7:3.2.4)
Homepage: http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/
Download-Size: 274 kB
APT-Sources: http://ftp.fi.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
Description: GPAC Project on Advanced Content - utilities
 GPAC stands for GPAC Project on Advanced Content (a recursive acronym). It is
 an Open Source multimedia framework for research and academic purposes. The
 project covers different aspects of multimedia, with a focus on presentation
 technologies (graphics, animation and interactivity).
 .
 This package contains the following utilities:
   - MP4Client (content packaging)
   - DashCast
   - MP4Box
   - MP42TS
```